# merge master to my feature branch overwrites changes in git

Tags: git

I have my feature-branch, the branch was merged to master and, after an error arised, the merge was reverted. Now when I try to merge master into my branch all my changes are overwritten by master, as if git thought my changes are older and shouldn't be merged.

I've found this solution: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

But I don't want to revert the revert so, is there a way of merging my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as the documentation you've linked explains, you can rebase your branch onto the commit it was originally branched from. This will rewrite the history and therefore allow you to remerge the branch. Note that you need to pass `--no-ff` to `git rebase`, otherwise it will just fast-forward and not change anything.

So, let's say you're working on a feature in a branch `feature1`.
The following illustrates the workflow:

```
$ git show --oneline
c7058f7 Initial commit
$ git checkout -b feature1
$ echo "feature" > feature1
$ git add feature1
$ git commit -m "feature1"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature1
$ git revert -m 1 HEAD
$ git checkout feature1
$ git rebase --no-ff c7058f7
$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature1
$ git log
commit 9bc0016d5c412ed7b9401bf0fd8fe5519a235a9f
Merge: fa2b2cb 48e007b

    Merge branch 'feature1'

commit 48e007bcef4675981076d84d245a2a489340a509

    feature1

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

commit fa2b2cbe4192a80d3c660f84f9d5f4ba4a7f7ba7

    Revert "Merge branch 'feature1'"

    This reverts commit 578502c12340f5ba7df47976d9e22245b5e9d8f8, reversing
    changes made to c7058f7f1dbf6409bfbc44a61eda1adf1155a981.

 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)

commit 578502c12340f5ba7df47976d9e22245b5e9d8f8
Merge: c7058f7 7b4690e

    Merge branch 'feature1'

commit 7b4690e19b45a089bc0db44cf66ebfa3495e48f9

    feature1

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

commit c7058f7f1dbf6409bfbc44a61eda1adf1155a981

    Initial commit
```

This is summarized in [How to revert a faulty merge](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt):

> But if you don’t actually need to change commit A, then you need some
>   way to recreate it as a new commit with the same changes in it. The
>   rebase command’s --no-ff option provides a way to do this:
>
> ```
> $ git rebase [-i] --no-ff P
> ```
>
> The --no-ff option creates a new branch A'-B'-C' with all-new commits
>   (all the SHA IDs will be different) even if in the interactive case
>   you only actually modify commit B. You can then merge this new branch
>   directly into the mainline branch and be sure you’ll get all of the
>   branch’s changes.
>
> You can also use --no-ff in cases where you just add extra commits to
>   the topic to fix it up. Let’s revisit the situation discussed at the
>   start of this howto:
>
> ```
> P---o---o---M---x---x---W---x
>  \         /
>   A---B---C----------------D---E   <-- fixed-up topic branch
> ```
>
> At this point, you can use --no-ff to recreate the topic branch:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout E
> $ git rebase --no-ff P
> ```
>
> yielding
>
> ```
>   A'---B'---C'------------D'---E'  <-- recreated topic branch
>  /
> P---o---o---M---x---x---W---x
>  \         /
>   A---B---C----------------D---E
> ```
>
> You can merge the recreated branch into the mainline without reverting
>   commit W, and mainline’s history will look like this:
>
> ```
>   A'---B'---C'------------D'---E'
>  /                              \
> P---o---o---M---x---x---W---x---M2
>  \         /
>   A---B---C
> ```